# Android: rows don't inserting.

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm really confused about this issue. General architecture of my app:
I'm using Retrofit to retrieve data from Foursquare. *(As I checked response is fine.)* In my `Service` class I persist data in my local database and send message to my `Fragment` after. I browsed my database, tables are created - but for unclear reason my database stays empty. Logging doesn't help much. 
Here is my related code.

**WebService** class(I just removed my secret keys):

```
private void handleExploreVenues(Intent intent) {
        String ll = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_LL);
        String radius = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_RADIUS);
        String limit = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_LIMIT);
        String offset = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRAS_OFFSET);

        parametersMap = new HashMap<>();
        parametersMap.put(EXTRAS_LL, ll);
        parametersMap.put(EXTRAS_LIMIT, limit);
        parametersMap.put(EXTRAS_RADIUS, radius);
        parametersMap.put(EXTRAS_OFFSET, offset);

        parametersMap.put("client_secret", "");//
        parametersMap.put("client_id", "");//
        parametersMap.put("v", "20160215");
        parametersMap.put("venuePhotos", "1");

        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ApiRequests client = RESTClient.createRetrofitClient(ApiRequests.class);
                Call<ExploreResponse> call = client.exploreVenues(parametersMap);
                try {

                    exploreResponse = call.execute().body();
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "explore response is null: " + (exploreResponse == null));

                    if (exploreResponse != null) {
                        DBDataSource dbDataSource = new DBDataSource(getApplicationContext());
                        dbDataSource.open();
                        dbDataSource.saveVenueList(exploreResponse.getResponse().getGroups().get(0).getItems());
                        dbDataSource.close();
                        OttoBus.getInstance().post(new VenuesPreparedEvent());
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Exception during exploring venues");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

**DBDataSource** class:

```
public class DBDataSource {

    private SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private final String LOG_TAG = DBDataSource.class.getSimpleName();
    private String[] allColumnsVenues = {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VENUE_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_RATING,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_RATING_COLOR,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_LOCATION_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_PHOTO_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_PHONE};

    private String[] allColumnsLocation = {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_LAT,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_LNG
    };
    private String[] allColumnsPhoto = {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_PREFIX,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_SUFFIX
    };

    public DBDataSource(Context context) {
        dbHelper = DBHelper.getInstance(context);
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        database.close();
    }

    public void saveVenue(Venue venue) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, venue.getId());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VENUE_NAME, venue.getName());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATING, venue.getRating());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_RATING_COLOR, venue.getRatingColor());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_PHONE, venue.getContact().getFormattedPhone());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LOCATION_ID, saveLocation(venue.getLocation()));
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_PHOTO_ID, savePhoto(venue.getFeaturedPhotos().getItems().get(0)));

        long insertResp = database.insertWithOnConflict(DBHelper.TABLE_VENUES, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inserting venue response " + insertResp);
    }

    public void saveVenueList(List<Item> itemList) {
        database.beginTransaction();
        try {
            for (Item item : itemList) {
                Venue venue = item.getVenue();
                saveVenue(venue);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "exception during venue saving");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            database.endTransaction();
        }
    }

    public List<Venue> getAllVenues() {
        List<Venue> venueList = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VENUES, allColumnsVenues, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Venue venue = cursorToVenue(cursor);
            venueList.add(venue);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return venueList;
    }

    public long saveLocation(Location location) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS, location.getAddress());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LNG, location.getLng());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_LAT, location.getLat());
        long insertLocationResp = database.insertWithOnConflict(DBHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inserting location response " + insertLocationResp);

        return insertLocationResp;
    }



    public String savePhoto(Item___ item___) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, item___.getId());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_PREFIX, item___.getPrefix());
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_SUFFIX, item___.getSuffix());

        long insertPhotoResp = database.insertWithOnConflict(DBHelper.TABLE_PHOTOS, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "inserting photo response " + insertPhotoResp);
        return item___.getId();
    }

    private Location getRelevantLocation(int locationID) {
        String restrict = DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + locationID;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(true, DBHelper.TABLE_LOCATIONS, allColumnsLocation, restrict, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursorToLocation(cursor);
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Location cursorToLocation(Cursor cursor) {
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setAddress(cursor.getString(1));
        location.setLat(cursor.getDouble(2));
        location.setLng(cursor.getDouble(3));
        return location;
    }

    private Photos getRelevantPhoto(int photoID) {
        String restrict = DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + "=" + photoID;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(true, DBHelper.TABLE_PHOTOS, allColumnsPhoto, restrict, null, null, null,
                null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            //because of big amount of nested lists and object this part looks really ugly. Reconsider possible solutions
            Item__ item__ = cursorToPhoto(cursor);
            Photos photos = new Photos();
            List<Item__> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(item__);
            List<Group_> group_list = new ArrayList<>();
            Group_ group = new Group_();
            group.setItems(list);
            group_list.add(group);
            photos.setGroups(group_list);
            return photos;
        }
        // Make sure to close the cursor
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private Item__ cursorToPhoto(Cursor cursor) {
        Item__ item__ = new Item__();
        item__.setId(cursor.getString(0));
        item__.setPrefix(cursor.getString(1));
        item__.setSuffix(cursor.getString(2));
        return item__;

    }

    private Venue cursorToVenue(Cursor cursor) {
        Venue venue = new Venue();
        venue.setId(cursor.getString(0));
        venue.setName(cursor.getString(1));
        venue.setRating(cursor.getDouble(2));
        venue.setRatingColor(cursor.getString(3));
        venue.setLocation(getRelevantLocation(cursor.getInt(4)));
        venue.setPhotos(getRelevantPhoto(cursor.getInt(5)));
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        contact.setPhone(cursor.getString(6));
        venue.setContact(contact);
        return venue;
    }

}
```

And my **DBHelper** class( just in case I missed something):

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private final String LOG_TAG = DBHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    public static final String DB_NAME = "LocalVenues.db";
    public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    //TODO ADD PRICES TABLE AND REFERENCE
    public static final String TABLE_VENUES = "venues";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENUE_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING = "rating";
    public static final String COLUMN_RATING_COLOR = "rating_color";
    public static final String COLUMN_LOCATION_ID = "location_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHOTO_ID = "photo_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";

    //tips
    public static final String TABLE_TIPS = "tips";
    public static final String COLUMN_VENUE_ID = "venue_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_TIP_TEXT = "text";
    public static final String COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID = "user_id";

    //locations
    public static final String TABLE_LOCATIONS = "locations";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "lat";
    public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "lng";

    //authors
    public static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRST_NAME = "first_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAST_NAME = "last_name";

    //photos
    public static final String TABLE_PHOTOS = "photos";
    public static final String COLUMN_PREFIX = "prefix";
    public static final String COLUMN_SUFFIX = "suffix";



    private static DBHelper dbHelperInstance;

    private DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public static synchronized DBHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (dbHelperInstance == null) {
            return dbHelperInstance = new DBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        } else {
            return dbHelperInstance;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigure(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onConfigure(db);
        db.setForeignKeyConstraintsEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String STM_CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE ";

        String STM_PRIMARY_KEY = "PRIMARY KEY ";
        String STM_FOREIGN_KEY = " FOREIGN KEY ";
        String STM_REFERENCES = " REFERENCES ";
        String STM_TEXT = " TEXT ";
        String STM_AUTOINCREMENT = " AUTOINCREMENT, ";

        String STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY = STM_TEXT + STM_PRIMARY_KEY;
        String STM_NOT_NULL = " NOT NULL, ";
        String STM_REAL = " REAL ";
        String STM_INTEGER = " INTEGER ";


        String CREATE_TABLE_VENUES = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_VENUES + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_VENUE_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_RATING + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_RATING_COLOR + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + STM_INTEGER + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_PHONE + STM_TEXT + ", " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_LOCATION_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_LOCATIONS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ") "
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_LOCATIONS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_INTEGER + STM_PRIMARY_KEY + STM_AUTOINCREMENT +
                COLUMN_ADDRESS + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LAT + STM_REAL + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LNG + STM_REAL + "NOT NULL"
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_PHOTOS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PREFIX + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_SUFFIX + STM_TEXT + "NOT NULL"
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_USERS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_USERS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_LAST_NAME + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + " ( " + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + " ) " + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + " (" + COLUMN_ID + " ) "
                + ");";

        String CREATE_TABLE_TIPS = STM_CREATE_TABLE + TABLE_TIPS + " ( " +
                COLUMN_ID + STM_TEXT_PRIMARY_KEY + ", " +
                COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_VENUE_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                COLUMN_TIP_TEXT + STM_TEXT + STM_NOT_NULL +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_VENUE_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_VENUES + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_AUTHOR_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_USERS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + "), " +
                STM_FOREIGN_KEY + "(" + COLUMN_PHOTO_ID + ")" + STM_REFERENCES + TABLE_PHOTOS + "(" + COLUMN_ID + ") "
                + ");";


        Log.i(LOG_TAG, CREATE_TABLE_VENUES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_VENUES);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_LOCATIONS);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PHOTOS);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USERS);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, CREATE_TABLE_TIPS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TIPS);


    }

    //The simplest implementation of onUpgrade() method
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        String STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ";
        if (oldVersion != newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_VENUES);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_LOCATIONS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_PHOTOS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_TIPS);
            db.execSQL(STM_DROP_TABLE_IF_EXISTS + TABLE_USERS);
        }
    }
}
```

In my log I checked insert code and it looks what is strange:

```
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/WebService: explore response is null: false
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 1
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 1
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 1
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 2
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 2
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 2
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 3
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 3
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 3
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 4
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 4
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 4
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 5
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 5
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 5
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 6
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 6
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 6
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 7
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 7
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 7
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 8
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 8
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 8
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 9
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 9
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 9
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting location response 10
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting photo response 10
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/DBDataSource: inserting venue response 10
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/ListFragment:  event from service received
2965-2982/com.localvenues I/ListFragment: check venues from DB - is empty: true
```

I just don't get where is the problem. Nor exception, neither warning. I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before `endTransaction()` to actually commit the changes to database. A transaction ended without being set as successful is a rollback.

Comment: Thank you very much. I missed this moment.